# Increase USB HS transfer rate above 100 megabits

Tags: usb, high-speed, cdc

There is a device. On board, STM32F446 + USB3315 as PHY + USB HUB assembled on USB2503. Frequency APB 180 MHz
A device project with a CDC interface has been created in CUbeMX. On command from the host, the device transmits a large amount of data - about 25 megabytes. The problem is speed. The speed does not rise above 100 megabits/sec. When the block transfer is completed, a callback is called that starts sending a new chunk. Analysis of the interrupt showed that the processor spends all the time inside the USB_HS interrupt handler at the time of the transfer. DMA is not used (not implemented in the HAL). I tried to play with the size of FIFO per transfer, there is no difference either. It doesn't matter where to get data from, from external memory or from internal, it does not affect the speed. This is the maximum speed for this processor, or it is possible to increase performance?

Comment: I myself answer. 1 enable DMA.  in the file **usbd_conf.c** make FIFO settings change 'HAL_PCDEx_SetRxFiFo(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, 0x200);
  HAL_PCDEx_SetTxFiFo(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, 0, 0x80);
  HAL_PCDEx_SetTxFiFo(&hpcd_USB_OTG_HS, 1, 0x100);' Cube creates incorrect settings

Comment: You may want to post this as an answer rather than a comment. You'll have more space and the ability to format your answer. And you will even be able to accept your own answer :-)

Comment: we might even be able to upvote that answer then!